# SELECT BOTTOM without changing ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm new to SQL and wondering is it possible to select the bottom n rows without using `SELECT TOP` and then `ORDER BY`.

I can find numerous examples of mimicing the idea with `SELECT TOP` & then `ORDER BY` e.g. [How to select bottom most rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1876606) but I need to keep my data sorted in the opposite order so using `ORDER BY` isn't ideal.

My below query returns the data points I need to pass through to my other programmes but now the data comes out sorted in the opposite direction than desired and causes issues.

```
SELECT TOP 504 
date
,price

FROM
[dbo].[AssetRet]

WHERE
asset = 'SP500'

ORDER BY
date DESC
```

I could get round this by putting a filter on `date` on remove `TOP` but I'm not sure how to do this i.e.:

```
WHERE
date > Min(Select DISTINCT TOP 504 date FROM [dbo].[AssetRet] ORDER BY date DESC)
```

I hope it is possible via SQL to `SELECT BOTTOM` without `ORDER BY`; else I will have to just flip the data after the SQL query in the other program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just wrap it in another query and put in the order you require...

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM   (
       SELECT TOP 504 
              "date",
              price
       FROM   [dbo].[AssetRet]
       WHERE  asset = 'SP500'
       ORDER BY "date" DESC
       ) x 
ORDER BY x."date"
```

Does this alternative work?...you will need a later version of sql-server for the partition function `RANK`...

```
SELECT x."date",
       x.price
FROM   (
       SELECT "date",
              price,
              Rnk = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "date" DESC)
       FROM  [dbo].[AssetRet]
       WHERE asset = 'SP500'
       ) x 
WHERE  x.Rnk <= 504
ORDER BY x."date"
```

**EDIT**
Looks like **[this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876606/how-to-select-bottom-most-rows?lq=1)** pretty much covered your question

Comment: No problem - glad I could help - what version of sql-server are you using? Did the second suggestion not work?

Comment: The second suggestion worked perfectly too, thanks.... first suggestion seems a bit easier to implement

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand what you're after, but you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in place of top/bottom, you can use it to get both TOP and BOTTOM if you wanted:

```
SELECT date, price
FROM (SELECT     date
               , price
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) 'RowRankASC'
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) 'RowRankDESC'
        FROM AssetRet
        WHERE asset = 'SP500'
     )sub
WHERE RowRankASC <= 504
     OR RowRankDESC <= 504
ORDER BY date
```