# Select middle rows in sql query

Tags: php, sql

I have a table of 1000 records of data. If i want to get data of rows from 501 to 700 from the table without using any condition what I have to do.Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Which SQL version are you using?   I am guessing MySQL?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876606/how-to-select-bottom-most-rows . You should be able to do it in two passes: first pass to select top, second pass to select bottom (or the reverse).

Comment: Have you tried any thing?

Answer (score 6):

I guess you can use `LIMIT` like this :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
    LIMIT 500,200; -- get data of rows from 501 to 700
```

Moreover, you should not rely data to be sorted with primary key by default, so add an ORDER BY statement :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
    ORDER BY primary_key
    LIMIT 500,200; -- get data of rows from 501 to 700
```

Comment: Note that without an `order by` the returned data is random

Comment: @techsolutions: don't forget to accept this answer, if it worked for you. To accept an answer, click on the 'tick' mark to the left, so it turns green. This is how we mark a question as solved here.